# How to upload video from the API imgur

Tags: imgur

I'm using imgur API and I have several question, what is the size limit for uploading a .gif ? I read everywhere the size limit of picture is 10Mb and gif are 20Mb but when I try to upload a gif of 11Mb with the API it tells me it's too heavy.

Also Im trying to upload a video (.mp4 , 6,9Mb) and I use the following request with postman

```
https://api.imgur.com/3/image?client_id={myclientid}
```

and in the body

```
  video={mavideo.mp4}
```

but it return me a success with no information

```
{
"data": {
"errorCode": null,
"ticket": "90c70cdc"
},
"success": true,
"status": 200
}
```

I have followed the api documentation to make this request

Thank you.

EDIT:

Ok it work if I'm using 
`https://api.imgur.com/3/upload` in postman but when I try to use it with ajax like this

```
if (fileExtension == "mp4" || fileExtension == "webm"){
     form.append('video', file);
    } else {
     form.append('img', file);
    }
$.ajax({
     url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload',
     headers: {
     Authorization: "Client-ID " + ClientId },
     type: 'POST',
     data: form,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false
 })
```

I have got the message `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:3010' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
What is wrong ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not at all. Imgur support told me to post on stackoverflow and developer would answer me but it didn't work. I just avoid to use Imgur for webm and mp4

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but we both seem to be trying to get this working at the same time, so i will share what i found out.

As you seem to have found out also, there are 2 endpoints for uploading, `/image` and `/upload`.

When uploading video, `/image` returns a ticket id. This is probably meant to get the state of the queued processing. There is however no endpoint available where you can send the ticket id and get the state back.

Second endpont, `/upload` has however another bunch of issues.

While it does return a  more useable object with image id and url, it seems to completely ignore the authorization header. Any image that i managed to upload this way has null for the uploaded user, and i don't see it in my account. (using oauth2 and sending `Authorization: Bearer <token>`) Even if i omit the header completely, it still works even though Authorization is mandatory for uploading.

Another weird thing is, if i don't send the auth header BUT add anything to the query params (so `?some=thing` or whatever) it suddenly wakes up and starts requiring the authorization header. When i send it again at this point however, we are back at the beginning and even the `/upload` endpoint starts sending ticket id and not a reasonable response.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing, also I don't know why but on the doc https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139 `/upload` is the only request with a lock icon. I have tried to contact the support but they keep redirect me to stackoverflow.

Comment: Not sure if you are still searching for a way to do this, but:
/upload now seems to work
album parameter does not add it to an existing album - need to use an endpoint for that
but it correctly uploads it under your account
@Gaeguri

Answer (score 1):

This is a CORS issue and needs to be fixed by the imgur devs. It's only an issue when doing client-side JavaScript as `curl` works just fine:

```
echo 'R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7' | base64 --decode | curl --location --request POST 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload' --header "Authorization: Client-ID $CLIENT_ID" -F 'type=file' -F 'disable_audio=0' -F 'image=@-'
```