# how to add video imgur

Tags: html, web, frontend, imgur

I need to add a video from imgur.com.

I have an html file, I was asked to place a video from imgur.com on the page, but unfortunately none of the options did not work for me, the option with  does not work either. Could you please tell me how I should change the html document to make it work correctly? Thank you very much.
[right now my video looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA2LG.png)

I read
https://apidocs.imgur.com/
[How to upload video from the API imgur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233881/how-to-upload-video-from-the-api-imgur)
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video
[images from imgur.com is not displaying on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489569/images-from-imgur-com-is-not-displaying-on-website)
I've also watched various youtube videos about it.
I may have missed something and would be glad if someone could point out my mistake. thank you all!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.